# asp.net page renders ASCII codes

Tags: ascii

We have an asp.net website and when we publish the site and deploy it to IIS every thing is fine but one page. No Html is renderd only ASCII Codes .

First Line :
}�Lx���9M����EKo~=#J��,�ѻ���l�^�f��ϫe�}�-����G?�׳l�}tȟ^��ż}���EV�GM���Q:~�/

view source shows exactly the same content (No HTML) .
We have used WebSockets in our project for chat and it works fine in other pages.

Comment: What HTTP headers are sent along with that content?